# Neo4j Eager and Optional Match Issues

Tags: neo4j, eager-loading

When I try to execute the following query (to create a relationship between teachers and students), I see an eager pop up in the profile:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/AFile" as line
WITH line
MATCH (teacher:Teacher {ValueOne: toInt(line.ValueOne)})
MATCH (bully:Bully { Value2:toInt(line.ValueTwo)})
MATCH (bully)-[:LOVES]->(student:Student)
CREATE (student)<-[:HELPS]-(teacher)
;
```

The result of a profile looks like:

- Empty Result
- Update Graph
- Eager
- Filter(0)
- SimplePatternMatcher
- SchemaIndex(0)
- SchemaIndex(1)
- ColumnFilter
- Filter(1)
- Extract
- Slice
- LoadCSV

Someone recommended optional matches [here](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/689), which I attempted to do on the last match:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (bully)-[:LOVES]->(student:Student)
WHERE student IS NOT NULL
```

This resulted in the error:

> Other node is null.

I also tried limiting the student match to return only a single student, but this didn't work either. However, I don't think I'm doing it correctly, where I add WITH student LIMIT 1.

Does anyone have recommendations for how to reduce the number of eagers? Without the create at the end, I don't get an eager, and with it I do.

Following Stefan's suggestion, I'm no longer getting an eager, but I am getting the "Other node is null" error.

- Empty Result
- UpdateGraph
- Optional Match
- SchemaIndex(0)
- SchemaIndex(1)
- Slice
- ColumnFilter
- Filter(0)
- Extract
- LoadCSV
- Filter(1)
- SimplePatternMatcher
- Argument

Answer (score 1):

At least in 2.2.2 the following seems not to have an `eager`:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/AFile" as line
WITH line
MATCH (teacher:Teacher {ValueOne: toInt(line.ValueOne)})
MATCH (bully:Bully { Value2:toInt(line.ValueTwo)})
OPTIONAL MATCH (bully)-[:LOVES]->(student)
WHERE student IS NOT NULL and "Student" in labels(student)
MERGE (student)<-[:HELPS]-(teacher)
```

The error "other node is null" seems to pop up when doing an optional match with a label on the other end.

Comment: I'm still hitting a 'other node is null" when I use the optional match

Comment: even without specifying a label in the `OPTIONAL MATCH`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's the case.

Comment: can you provide the current database (aka the graph.db folder) and the first ~100 lines of your csv?